# Read/Select:Connection reset by peer (10054) during remote logoff in RealVNC

Tags: logoff, vnc

I am using RealVNC 4.5 Enterprise on my Windows 7 client. I use this to connect to a remote system which is also running RealVNC 4.5 (on Windows 7 again).

And then i logoff the remote system (server) and all of a sudden the realvnc viewer on the client closes with the message : "Read/Select:Connection reset by peer (10054)" It also asks if i want to reconnect again. Any idea why this is happening and how do i resolve this?

Answer (score 2):

I find it !
Enable protocol 3.3 and use VNC password with encryption : prefer of :)

Comment: Not working when connect to Win7 from Win10, no encryption though snice open real vnc doesn't support that.

Answer (score 1):

This is a known problem with realVNC 4.5. It happens only in Windows 7; not in Windows XP;
Hopefully they come up with a solution to this soon;